# Complex Mapping of $\mathrm{cosh}(w)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Mapping in complex analysis has not been very easy for me unfortunately. I am having difficult trying to find the mapping between the z and w plane. I attempted to simply write that

$w=\cosh^{-1}{z}$

and applying

$\cosh^{-1}{z}=\log(z+(z^2-1)^{1/2})$

and trying to plug in $z=x+iy$ to get a relation between $z$ and $w$ such that w:

$w=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Is the way to go about it. This is how I have been handling mapping problems but there doesn't seem to be a clear cut way of doing the simplification in this problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For example $z^2$ has a mapping to the u-v plane related by $u=x^2 -y^2$ and $v=2xy$ (since $z^2 = (x^2 -y^2)+i(2xy)$)and a constant line in the u-v plane corresponds to a hyperbolic curve in the x-y plane. I am trying to find this same relationship with the function w above.